# How get data from JFrame Component Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I need get some data from "Board" Component but i dont know how. I tried Frame.Component.data but is doesn't work.
Code:

```
public class window extends JFrame {
public  window() {

   add(new Board());

    setResizable(true);
    pack();
    setTitle("Game");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {


    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame ex = new window();
        ex.setVisible(true);
        ex.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                //ex.Board.data
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    });
}}
```

Comment: why don t store your bord implem in a specific field ?

Comment: I just wanted to have direct access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a little tip to have a quick answer : reduced your code at the minimun to reproduced your bug its easier to understand especially in your case where your real purpose is in a comment ... and then make it compilable ...

To answer to your issue : personnaly i use dedicated fields to have a direct link to object i want to handle later there is two reason first a field is easy to use and don't use lot of memory . Second this solution will not depend on the way your frame is organised. an other way to get the same result is the second snippet the probelme is that if you change your frame organisation you will have to modify your listener

```
package so1;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3000003489937872937L;

    public class Data {
        public void doSomethings() {
            System.out.println("toto");
        }
    }

    public class Board extends JLabel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7362684018638848838L;
        private Data data = new Data();

    }

    private Board board;

    public Window() {
        board = new Board();
        add(board);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window ex = new Window();
        ex.setVisible(true);
        ex.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                ex.board.data.doSomethings();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the bad solution :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window ex = new Window();
        ex.setVisible(true);
        ex.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                ((Board)((JPanel)((JLayeredPane)((JRootPane)ex.getComponents()[0]).getComponents()[1]).getComponents()[0]).getComponents()[0]).data.doSomethings();;
            }
        });
    }
```